# Equating a Double with a calculated Double value from a method results in 0.0? What could be the problem?

Tags: java, if-statement, casting, double

For these expressions:

```
     if (lim != null) {


         for (int i = 0; i < itemlist.size(); i++) {              

            Double itemquantity = calculateQuantity(itemlist.get(i));

            Integer limitvalue = lim.getValue();

            System.out.println("CALCULATED VALUE IS: " + calculateQuantity(itemlist.get(i)));

            System.out.println("ITEMQUANTITY IS " + itemquantity);

            System.out.println("LIMIT VALUE IS " + limitvalue);

           if (itemquantity < limitvalue) {
               System.out.println("QUANTITY " + itemquantity + " vs LIMIT " + limitvalue);
           below.add(itemlist.get(i).getName());
        }}
```

I get the following results:

```
CALCULATED VALUE IS: **210.0** 
ITEMQUANTITY IS **0.0** 
LIMIT VALUE IS **500** 
QUANTITY 0.0 vs LIMIT 500
```

Here is the is the calculateQuantity() method which returns a Double, but this method works as seen by the output:

```
     public Double calculateQuantity(Items item)
        {
        Double quantity = 0.0;     
        int ID = item.getItemId();
            try {
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();
                transaction = session.beginTransaction();

                Query query = session.createQuery("select sum(t.flow * a.inOrOut) from Advicenote a join a.transactions t join t.item i where i.itemId = :keyword group by i.itemId");

                query.setParameter("keyword", ID);
                transaction.commit();
                if (query.uniqueResult() == null || query.list().isEmpty()) {
                    quantity = 0.0;                
                } 
                else{     
                quantity = Double.valueOf(query.uniqueResult().toString()); 

                }}catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }

}finally{
                        session.close();
                        return quantity;
                        }}
```

So my question is, **why I get 0 when I try to equate the result of calculateQuantity() with a Double value?** And how could make the `itemquantity < limitvalue` if statement work (the former should be a Double/double and the latter an Integer/int)?

Comment: use a debugger and check the behaviour during the first call to `calculateQuantity`. My guess is the first query result is not what you expect

Comment: @jhamon but I print out its value and it's equal to `CALCULATED VALUE IS: 210.0`

Comment: no, you print out the result of a **second** call to `calculateQuantity`. So the query is re-executed hence the result may be different. That's why you need to use a step-by-step debugger

Comment: Either query has no result, too many results or an exception is thrown

Comment: I am not so much into DB queries, is there really a need for a **transaction** for a READ? (the method is named computeQuantity(), and I find it surprising what it is actually doing ... that is rarely a good sign) Beyond that, wouldn't it be better to at least log something in your catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the branch under

```
    if(query.uniqueResult() == null || query.list().isEmpty())
```

is firing. This means there is an issue with your query, which would be beyond the scope of this question.

The following should work:

```
    if(itemquantity < limitvalue)
```

Because Java supports comparison between different numerical types without explicit casting. double and int are both in that category.

Comment: But the method works, because when I print out `System.out.println("CALCULATED VALUE IS: " + calculateQuantity(itemlist.get(i)));` I get `CALCULATED VALUE IS: 210.0` which is what I expect to get, only when I equate this expression with `itemquantity` it turns to 0, that's why it's so weird...

Comment: @Fluellen It's possible the first time you run the method, it fails, and the second time it works because of changes made by the first time you ran it.